# How to convert emojis in website to an images?

Tags: javascript, html, text, replace, emoji

I just need my own emojis in my site. I was finding a script code in many site. But answer is useles and nothing.

Can you teach me to replace emojis or some emoticons like this
 :-)
 :-(
 8-)

To be replace to emoji images in png or gif animation format.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: with a simple research on google you can find many javascript plugins that do this

Comment: Yes. And i so many try to learn in site

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
 var map = {
   "<3": "\u2764\uFE0F",
   "</3": "\uD83D\uDC94",
   ":D": "\uD83D\uDE00",
   ":)": "\uD83D\uDE03",
   ";)": "\uD83D\uDE09",
   ":(": "\uD83D\uDE12",
   ":p": "\uD83D\uDE1B",
   ";p": "\uD83D\uDE1C",
   ":'(": "\uD83D\uDE22"
 };


 function toEmoji(emoji){
     return  map[emoji];
 }
 
console.log(toEmoji(":)"));
console.log(toEmoji(":'("));
```

Comment: \u2764\uFE0F that not looks like source image or i can change that to resorce image